# Dynamic Webpages how many TCP connections for each include/GET request

Tags: sockets, http, tcp

I have a semantic web/RDF application which runs on Tomcat and is backended with MySQL. Apache HTTPD is in front as a reverse proxy and the OS is Red Hat Linux 6. I am seeing a lot of Connections to port 80 per IP.  What I want to know is what determines whether the include for a css or .js file is served over the existing TCP socket, or a new one is created for each GET that occurs while the web page is "built".  Is that exclusively the application itself, or is it the Apache web server, or the Linux kernel as well?

Comment: I am wondering if the problem is that my Application does not send any Connection: keep-alive headers?

Comment: Is your app sending an HTTP 1.0 or 1.1 request? If there is no `Connection` header in the request then keep-alive is disabled by default in 1.0 and enabled by default in 1.1.

Comment: HTTP 1.1.  The only Connection headers I see are response headers with Connection: Close.

Comment: I have enabled Keep Alive in apache via KeepAlive On, and now I only see a few connections per request, per IP, and they seem to be not sitting in TIME_WAIT state.  Also the app seems faster.  Does this sounds rational?

Comment: Yes. `TIME_WAIT` is only for connections that have been closed. Connections that are kept alive can be reused for multiple requests, thus not wasting time reconnecting each time. So it sounds like keep-alive is doing its job.

Comment: One might ask then, why is KeepAlive off by default in Apache with HTTP/1.1 being the standard?

Comment: You will have to ask the Apache developers about that.